# How does DNS resolution work without any nameserver entries in resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, dns

I have a query on the purpose of the `resolv.conf` file.

If I delete the name server entry from the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, my browser still able to do the DNS query. As far as I know, any URL is first looked up in the name server which is listed on this file.

I read somewhere that if the `resolv.conf` entry is set to `localhost` then it means that the name server is running in the local host. Can someone point out which is that service?

After removing the name server entry from the `resolv.conf`, the commands like `nslookup` are not working as expected. However when I try to open a site from the browser, I see in the wireshark that the request is still sent to the same name server IP though I removed it from the `resolv.conf` file. This clearly means that there is some other name server service running.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network Manager uses dynamically your `/etc/resolv.conf` with `dnsmasq`. Each connection can have our dns server listed.

If you wish to avoid this behavior you can do this

In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` comment out the `dns=dnsmasq`

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:22:64:4E:6F:70,

[ifupdown]
managed=fals
```

and restart the NM service

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

With this `/etc/resolv.conf` is no longer dependant on resolvconf package and is updated based on the DNS entries of each connection in the Network Manager

Also you can add nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you have not set dns in NM per connection this will be used

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

You can stop and disable the `resolvconf` service and only use static defined dns servers from `/etc/resolv.conf`

Stop the service `resolvconf`

```
sudo service resolvconf stop
```

disable it

```
sudo update-rc.d resolvconf disable
```

disable `resolvconf` to overwrite `resolv.conf`

create `/etc/init/resolvconf.override` with single line manual

```
echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/resolvconf.override
```

remove symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

create `resolv.conf` with static dns entry

```
echo "namserver x.x.x.x." > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However, I am still not clear how will be the browser resolve say www.google.com if I remove the name server entry from the resolve.conf?

Comment: Also  I even removed dns-nameservers the entry from my /etc/network/interfaces file, but still the browser is able to resolve. Is there any other way it does the dns lookup?

Comment: On you `ubuntu` in `NM` have in the connection setup configured `DNS` server. Based on route, maybe is better to say, on witch connection traffic is routed `ubuntu` use that `DNS` and with `dnsmasq` make dynamic entry in `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you remove all `dns` setting from connection in `NM` you wouldn't be able to resolve logical names. To avoid that you can use static dns servers witch will resolve names and way to do that I write in answer.